# Kotlin: How can extension functions within a type be accessed externally?

Tags: function, extension-methods, kotlin

I often come across the scenario where I have abstract extension functions within a type.

```
interface PetScript {
    fun Pet.feed()
    fun Pet.call()
}
```

Having the functions be extension functions allows very minimalistic implementations because it gives automatic `this` context.

Unfortunately, the only way I know of to use these functions is to write boilerplate standard functions which pass to the extensions.

```
interface PetScript {
    fun Pet.feed()
    fun Pet.call()

    fun feed_(pet: Pet) = pet.feed()
    fun call_(pet: Pet) = pet.call()
}
```

This way I'm able to use the functions like so:

```
val pet = ...
val script = ...

script.feed_(pet)
script.call_(pet)
```

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to use the extension functions outside of the type?

Comment: Marked as a duplicate since the question seems to be the same. Please tell me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [longstanding ticket for multiple receivers on extension functions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10468), but the simple workaround is to nest your scope:

```
val pet = ...
val script = ...

script.run {
    pet.feed()
    pet.call()
}
```